# Python Google APIs

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I have just installed the Google APIs for Python, and yet, I tried to run anything to check if it works, like:

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
```

And it throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mszydlowski/Desktop/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\googlemaps.py", line 471
    print main.__doc__
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that googlemaps does not support py3k.
http://py-googlemaps.sourceforge.net/#information

Answer (score 1):

What version of Python are you using?  print is a function for Python 3.